# аудиоплеер на html5 воспроизводит музыку в новом окне

Tags: json, html5, плеер

Коллеги, помогите разобраться!
Есть муз.сайт.

1) На главной странице находятся последние добавленные песни.
Слева от каждой песни есть **однокнопочный плеер на html5 - UbaPlayer**. Очень лёгкий по размеру и понятный в освоении.
При нажатии на плеер - воспроизводится текущий трек. **Здесь всё работает исправно**, так, как мне надо. (скриншот 1)

2) Внизу - **кнопка "Ещё песни"**. Из БД посредством ajax (библиотекой JSON) тянутся ещё 20 песен. Выводятся песни верно, но с воспроизведением начинаются проблемы.

При нажатии на плеер, песня уже не воспроизводится, **но открывается в новом окне** и там уже играет. (скриншот 2).

У меня подозрение на JSON. Он же кодирует таким образом: \u043d хотя это распространяется только на кириллицу.

3) Код, отвечающий за вывод дополнительных 20ти песен с плеером, следующий:

```
if (data.length > 0){$.each(data, function(index, data){$("#novinki_plus").append("<div class='msongli'><div class='play'><ul class='ubaplayer-controls'><li><a class='ubaplayer-button' href='" + data.link + "' id='song-" + data.id + "' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-link='" + data.link + "'></a></li></ul><a href='/mp3/" + data.id + "/" + data.artist_id + "/' class='msong' title='Скачать песню " + data.title + "'>" + data.title + "</a><span class='infodata'>" + data.time + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + data.bitrate + " Kbs</span><span class='infosize'>" + data.size + " Mb</span></div></div>");}); inProcess = false; num += 20;}
```

Не пойму, почему-то код не правильно форматируется здесь, на сайте, поэтому прикладываю скриншот куска кода. Скриншоты пришлось совместить, т.к. я не могу выложить больше одного скрина, к сожалению. Мало репутации (((

**ВОПРОС: как сделать, чтобы в подгружаемом блоке плеер воспроизводил музыку в этом же окне, как и в основном блоке на главной странице?**

скриншот 1 - страница с музыкой и плеером к каждой песне

скриншот 2 - плеер в новом окне

скриншот 3 - код в phpDesigner

[image: три совмещённых скриншота]

Answer (score 1):

В `.done()` аякса после вставки html вам нужно заново переинициализировать UbaPlayer, так как на момент загрузки страницы новых элементов НЕТ, и на них обработчик UbaPlayer не повешен.

Comment: Вы можете накидать, как это примерно будет выглядеть? В аяксе не силён - скрипт брал готовый, только немного под себя переделал. Спасибо!